# iframe and using jquery to load table only and remove rows or columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi trying to get this working.

Have an iframe in a div. i am loading the  iframe with:

```
 <iframe src="abc.com" id="divtoshow" border="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

is it enough to type id to tell the iframe to only load that div and ignore other  divs code on page.

the next part is remove columns and rows in the table the iframe loaded. how do remove more then 1 of each? and is it the same to remove rows?

```
$('table tr').each(
    function(tr_idx,el){
        $(el).children('td').each(
            function(td_idx,el2){
                //i'm removing first columns..
                if(td_idx == 0){
                    el2.remove();
                }
        });//inner each
});//outer each
```

thank you

Comment: "is it enough to type id to tell the iframe to only load that div and ignore other divs code on page." - No.. this means the IFrame has the id "divstoshow", this does not affect its content.

Comment: can you access the iframe's content via js??
do you load content from the same domain? Because of same-origin-policy

Comment: What exactly do you need to remove?

Comment: yes its on the same domain. need to remove everything apart from a table. then once the table is loaded i would like to reove rows and colomns aswell

Answer (score 0):

Dwhizz,

Unless you are loading an iframe from the same domain it is HIGHLY unlikely (read as : impossible) to muck around with the contents of the iframe using any scripting language.  This is baked into the browsers and is a security issue.

So the quick answer is "No, you will not be able to do this, stop trying"

If you can get at the domain you are trying to load via AJAX then you might have some luck using jquery's AJAX.load shortcut.

reading: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html and do some google on "cross domain AJAX" or "cross domain iframe"

Comment: Gotcha, then if we assume you have access via JavaScript to the contents (why the iframe in that case but who cares.)

First, the iframe will load the entire page at the url, so you'd have to then use jquery or javascript to rip out just the div that you want.  An alternative is to look into jQuery's load - http://api.jquery.com/load/ .  This would let you load only a certain div from a url into any element.  That would be step one.

Comment: Now, on to the columns or rows, rows is easy as you've shown its just 

    $('table tr').each(function(index,ele) {}); ... 

columns are a bit harder and you end up either doing some crazy looping, or making use of nth child selectors - http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/ , so something like this:

   //remove the fourth columns, but note that this does not play    well with colspan, for that you have to loop like a crazy person.
   $('table td:nth-child(3)').remove() etc.